# Verilog - Assign an output that lasts more than 1 clock cycle

Tags: verilog, vivado

I have designed a simple sequence detector that works, but I am wondering how I can edit it so that the valid_password outputs as high for 3 clock cycles regardless of input changes.
Here is what I've set my valid_password as:

```
assign valid_password = (present_state==s8)&(pass_in==3);
```

I know I've set it so that it only outputs high for this one specific state and input value but I am very new to this so any advice for recommended syntax's I should look for is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try a delay register. Here `trigger` register will assert high when `valid_password` condition hits. This is then passed on for two cycles.

```
reg [2:0] trigger;

always@(posedge clk or negedge rstn)
begin
 if(!rstn)
  trigger <= 'd0;
 else
 begin
  trigger[0] <= (present_state==s8) & (pass_in==3);
  trigger[1] <= trigger[0];
  trigger[2] <= trigger[1];
 end
end

 assign valid_password = ( (present_state==s8)&(pass_in==3) ) | trigger[0] | trigger[1] | trigger[2];
```

Comment: oh I would like to try this but I have never used negedge or rstn, what changes would I need to make in my testbench?

Comment: You can use `posedge` in the `always` block and use `if(rstn)` in the given snippet. No change to TB is needed.

Comment: a short-hand: `|{(present_state==s8)&(pass_in==3), trigger[2:0]}`